# Is consul based discovery supported for spring cloud sleuth?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have been moving my eureka based micro services system to consul and I have most of the key features working, discovery, config management, and metadata tags as per the original application.

But I am having exception show up when I am using sleuth.  The original worked for eureka but with a consul based discovery here is the exception trace.

Is sleuth supported?

Here is the exception trace

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.stream.SleuthStreamAutoConfiguration$DiscoveryClientEndpointLocatorConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.stream.SleuthStreamAutoConfiguration$DiscoveryClientEndpointLocatorConfiguration.client; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: consulDiscoveryClient,discoveryClient
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at com.cisco.phisphere.customerservice.CustomerServiceApplication.main(CustomerServiceApplication.java:55)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.stream.SleuthStreamAutoConfiguration$DiscoveryClientEndpointLocatorConfiguration.client; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: consulDiscoveryClient,discoveryClient
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: consulDiscoveryClient,discoveryClient
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Yes, we do support Consul. We're testing that in our e2e tests - https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/brewery . Most likely you have some issues with your classpath. Can you post a sample project somewhere with your setup?

Comment: I went through the dependencies and found an errant eureka dependency that was brought in in a distant library.  After I removed it, the problem went away.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Cool! If you need anything else just ping us either here or on Gitter - https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth